# Multiple tables in lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm trying to fetch data from a database using a lambda expression, but I can't figure out how to use multiple tables.

In SQL I would write this:

```
SELECT item.* 
FROM Item item, ItemListType listType 
WHERE listType.DisplayName = 'student' AND listType.ID = item.ItemListTypeId
```

but how can I convert that to a lambda expression?

- `Item` table columns: `ID, ItemListTypeId`
- `ItemListType` table columns: `ID, Name`

I call a function and passes a name (which exists in `ItemListType`). I have managed to write a query for getting `ItemListType`, but I cannot understand how to use multiple tables in LINQ queries:

```
ItemListType result = await this.ItemListTypes
           .Include(i => i.Items).SingleAsync(i => i.Name == name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use several tables in nested *from* clauses

```
from item in db.Item
from listType in db.ItemListType
where listType.DisplayName == "student" && item.ItemListTypeId == listType.ID
select item
```

But better create *inner join* query:

```
from item in db.Item
join listType in db.ItemListType on item.ItemListTypeId equals listType.ID
where listType.DisplayName == "student"
select item
```

Same in lambda syntax:

```
db.ItemListType
  .Where(lt => lt.DisplayName == "student")
  .Join(db.Item, lt => lt.ID, i => i.ItemListTypeId, (lt,i) => i)
```

Or if you have navigation property for Items in ItemListType:

```
db.ItemListType
  .Where(lt => lt.DisplayName == "student")
  .SelectMany(lt => lt.Items)
```

Comment: Great! I'm just not sure how to use that in lambda. this is what I have now: ItemListType result = await this.ItemListTypes.Include(i => i.Items).SingleAsync(i => i.Name == name);

Comment: @TempTheRuler something like `await db.ItemListTypes.Where(lt => lt.DisplayName == "student").Join(db.Items, lt => lt.ID, i => i.ItemListTypeId, (lt,i) => i).ToListAsync()`

Comment: @TempTheRuler or if you have navigation property: `await this.ItemListTypes.Where(lt => lt.DisplayName == "student").SelectMany(lt => lt.Items).ToListAsync()`

Comment: thank you very much! that's exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @TempTheRuler you are welcome. Next time please provide your code too and specify why it's not working (error or results are not as you expect). That is very useful information for us and allows to provide more precise answers

Comment: I think I was celebrating to early ;) Maybe I should mention this is a asp.net core application using entity framework core and I'm trying to select from a DbSet. The problem is I cant find a Where method on the DbSet object

Comment: yes I will be more precise on my next question. thanks for your patience

Comment: @TempTheRuler make sure you have added LINQ namespace to your file `using System.Linq`